# Morphed past tense third person of verb дáть?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

дáть, past tense have four conjuntions. According to Starling the third person past tense seems a little "morphed". Does "да'ло'" seems correct to you?

да'л

дала'

да'ло'

да'ли

From:

http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/morph.cgi?flags=endnnnnn&root=config&word=%E4%E0%F2%FC

Answer (score 3):

It means both *да́ло* and *дало́* are acceptable.

Lopatin's *Русский орфографический словарь* seems to agree with that.

Comment: For example :

"Будет понятно, что им это да́ло в плане эффективности?" 
"...потому что только это тебе не да́ло обогнать..."

I was unable to find an example where "дало́" sound natural.

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич, I would use "дало́" in your examples, and can't make up an example with "да́ло" (except for poetry, where stress can be changed to fit the metre)... Maybe, it depends on the dialect?

Comment: Now that's really unexpected to me, since I know only 3 real-world examples of Russian dialect. (I mean подъезд/парадное, бордюр/поребрик and word ремок, which no one knows). I'm from Novosibirsk, and where the different stress comes from?

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич: it's ok, I didn't know the dictionary stress for *тесно* until I was 25, and that for *скомкать* until yesterday. I would have used *дало́* in both cases.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but to me (as a native) дАло sounds unnatural, only далО

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич, I was born in Moscow and live here most of my life, but have spent several years of my childhood in a small village in Kirov region. Language here and there differs in pronounciation and intonations, and also there are some words I've never heard in Moscow: "баско" - "круто, классно", "кандейка" - "сарай, хозблок", "шевяк" - "помет (куриный, например)", "пауты" - "слепни", and many names of plants and mushrooms. And in Moscow there is a word "миска", while in the village "миска" was named "чашка", "чашка" was "кружка", and "кружка" was "кружка", too :)

Comment: But in "дало" in both dialects the second syllable is usually stressed, as far as I remember. Although in Moscow I sometimes hear some people say "да́ло". And what is "ремок"? :)

Answer (score -1):

I have no clue with certain accents. In my accent, whenever I talk about past tense, I do put less stress on that -ло ending will still maintaining the “o” sound so I don’t confuse myself. So it ends up as Да’’ло’, putting a stress mark on the a while also putting a tiny one on the o. But to be fair, I’m an Uzbek, so I already sound weird when speaking Russian but I also have some issues with speech. Hope I still was of help.